# Fyne error: Attempt to access current Fyne app when none is started

Tags: go, fyne

I've been trying to figure out what is causing this error... Might just be me, but maybe you can see what i can't. Hopefully you can give me a helping hand.

Whenever I run my code it gives this error

> Fyne error:  Attempt to access current Fyne app when none is started
>
> go/pkg/mod/fyne.io/fyne/v2@v2.2.3/app.go:92

Any idea? Here is the code. and It runs*

```
// GoMark project main.go
// Version 1.3
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image/color"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/canvas"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/dialog"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/theme"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

var text = widget.NewMultiLineEntry() //Text entry
var textTitle = widget.NewLabel("")
var preview = widget.NewRichTextFromMarkdown("") //Preview side
var myWindow fyne.Window
var down_dir = ""
var filePath = "" // THIS WILL NOT EDIT PRESET!!! Look further down...
var savename = ""
var savenametxt = ""
var myApp = app.New()

func main() {
    myWindow = myApp.NewWindow("GoMark 1.3")
    // - - - Text editor / Preview - - -

    textTitle.SetText("UNSAVED DOCUMENT")
    left := container.NewBorder(nil, nil, nil, nil, text)
    middle := container.NewHSplit(left, preview)
    text.OnChanged = func(string) { //When someting is written or canged in the text entry, update with this function
        preview.ParseMarkdown(text.Text)
    }
    // - - - END - - -

    // - - - TOP SECTION - - -
    //Line creation
    line := canvas.NewLine(color.Black)
    line.StrokeWidth = 4
    savename := widget.NewEntry()
    savename.SetPlaceHolder("ABC123")

    //- - - Settings toolbar - - -
    settings := widget.NewToolbar(
        widget.NewToolbarAction(theme.ContentClearIcon(), func() {
            dialog.ShowConfirm("Do you want to clear document?", "", callback, myWindow)
        }),
        widget.NewToolbarSeparator(),
        widget.NewToolbarAction(theme.FolderNewIcon(), func() {
            log.Println("Save as Doc")
            dialog.ShowFileSave(DownloadDirectory, myWindow)
        }),
        widget.NewToolbarAction(theme.DocumentSaveIcon(), func() {
            log.Println("Save Doc")

            form_savename := widget.NewFormItem("", savename)
            form := dialog.NewForm("Save Name to S:", "Save", "Cancel", []*widget.FormItem{form_savename}, func(b bool) {
                if b == true {
                    fmt.Println("Save selected")
                    savenametxt = savename.Text
                    SaveToS(myWindow)
                    savename.SetText(savenametxt)
                }
            }, myWindow)
            form.Resize(fyne.NewSize(400, 200))
            form.Show()
        }),
    )

    //Combiner
    top := container.NewBorder(nil, line, nil, settings, textTitle)
    // - - - END - - -

    //Run the main fyne window
    main := container.NewBorder(top, nil, nil, nil, middle)
    myWindow.Resize(fyne.NewSize(1200, 800))
    myWindow.SetContent(main)
    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}

//Clear text confirmation
func callback(yes bool) {
    fmt.Println("Running Callback")
    if yes == true {
        fmt.Println("Text CLEAR")
        clean()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Text STAY")
    }
}

//Clear text box and preview
func clean() {
    text.Text = ""
    preview.ParseMarkdown(text.Text)
    text.Refresh()
    textTitle.Text = "UNSAVED DOCUMENT"
    textTitle.Refresh()
    dialog.ShowInformation("Text has been cleared", "", myWindow)
}

//Choose a Download folder
func DownloadDirectory(savedir fyne.URIWriteCloser, err error) {
    fmt.Println("Dialog")
    fmt.Println(savedir.URI())
}

//- - - Save to S: - - -
func SaveToS(myWindow fyne.Window) {
    if runtime.GOOS == "Windows" {
        filePath = "S:\\TMP\\DocMove" //EDIT DIR PRESET FOR WINDOWS
        filePath = filePath + "\\"
    } else {
        filePath = "/mnt/s/TMP/DocMove" // EDIT DIR PRESET FOR LINUX
        filePath = filePath + "/"
    }
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOOS)
    file, errC := os.Create(filePath + savenametxt + ".md")
    if errC != nil {
        dialog.ShowError(errC, myWindow)
        fmt.Println(errC)
        return
    } else {
        _, errWriting := file.Write([]byte(text.Text))
        if errWriting != nil {
            dialog.ShowError(errWriting, myWindow)
            fmt.Println(errWriting)
            return
        } else {
            textTitle.SetText(savenametxt)
            dialog.ShowInformation("Sucess", savenametxt+" Has been saved", myWindow)
            fmt.Println(filePath + savenametxt + ".md")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create widgets before the fyne app is initiated.

This order gave me no errors:

```
var down_dir = ""
var filePath = "" // THIS WILL NOT EDIT PRESET!!! Look further down...
var savename = ""
var savenametxt = ""
var myApp = app.New()
var text = widget.NewMultiLineEntry() //Text entry
var textTitle = widget.NewLabel("")
var preview = widget.NewRichTextFromMarkdown("") //Preview side
var myWindow fyne.Window
```